# daz character missing root bone in blender

Tags: rigging, import

I wonder if anyone knows why a rigged character imported to blender from Daz studio doesn’t have the ability to kneel. I don’t see the root bone, so I guess that may be the problem. Can anyone tell me how to solve this? When I try to make the character kneel, moving the pelvis bone or the lower abdomen bones, I instead drag the bone down while everything else stays in place.
Thank you!

Comment: How did you import the character into blender? Different importer methods can produce different results. I strongly suggest trying to set up the Daz importer addon here: https://blenderartists.org/t/daz-importer/684697. It takes a little bit to set up, but should generally give good results for the rigging.

Comment: hard to tell, please share your armature: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/